# Seeking help to improve a crawler

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm a beginner with **Scrapy/Python**, I developed a crawler that can find **expired domains** and scan each on a **SEO API**.
My crawler work fine but I pretty sure the crawler isn't 100% optimized for the job.
Could it be possible to have some tricks to improve the Crawler please ?

**expired.py :**

```
class HttpbinSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "expired"

    rules = (
        Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.com', '.fr', '.net', '.org', '.info', '.casino', '.eu'),
                               deny=('facebook', 'amazon', 'wordpress', 'blogspot', 'free', 'reddit'),
             callback='parse_obj',
             process_request='add_errback',
             follow=True),
    )

    def __init__(self, domains=None, **kwargs):
        self.start_urls = json.loads(domains)
        super(HttpbinSpider, self).__init__()

    def add_errback(self, request):
        return request.replace(errback=self.errback_httpbin)

    def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
        if failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            request = failure.request
            ext = tldextract.extract(request.url)
            domain = ext.registered_domain
            if domain != '':
                domain = domain.replace("%20", "")
                self.check_domain(domain)

    def check_domain(self, domain):
        if self.is_available(domain) == 'AVAILABLE':

            self.logger.info('## Domain Expired : %s', domain)

            url = 'http://api.majestic.com/api/json?app_api_key=API&cmd=GetIndexItemInfo&items=1&item0=' + domain + '&datasource=fresh'
            response = urllib.urlopen(url)
            data = json.loads(response.read())
            response.close()

            TrustFlow = data['DataTables']['Results']['Data'][0]['TrustFlow']
            CitationFlow = data['DataTables']['Results']['Data'][0]['CitationFlow']
            RefDomains = data['DataTables']['Results']['Data'][0]['RefDomains']
            ExtBackLinks = data['DataTables']['Results']['Data'][0]['ExtBackLinks']

            if (RefDomains > 20) and (TrustFlow > 4) and (CitationFlow > 4):
                insert_table(domain, TrustFlow, CitationFlow, RefDomains, ExtBackLinks)

    def is_available(self, domain):
        url = 'https://api.internet.bs/Domain/Check?ApiKey=KEY&Password=PSWD&responseformat=json&domain' + domain
        response = urllib.urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(response.read())
        response.close()
        return data['status']
```

Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue in your code is urllib requests that are blocking whole async scrapy routine. You can easily replace those with scrapy request chain by yielding a `scrapy.Request`.

Something like this:

```
def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
    if not failure.check(DNSLookupError):
        return
    request = failure.request
    ext = tldextract.extract(request.url)
    domain = ext.registered_domain
    if domain == '':
        logging.debug('no domain: {}'.format(request.url))
        return
    domain = domain.replace("%20", "")
    url = 'https://api.internet.bs/Domain/Check?ApiKey=KEY&Password=PSWD&responseformat=json&domain=' + domain
    return Request(url, self.parse_checkdomain)

def parse_checkdomain(self, response):
    """check whether domain is available"""
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    if data['status'] == 'AVAILABLE':
        self.logger.info('Domain Expired : {}'.format(data['domain']))
        url = 'http://api.majestic.com/api/json?app_api_key=API&cmd=GetIndexItemInfo&items=1&item0=' + data['domain']+ '&datasource=fresh'
        return Request(url, self.parse_claim)

def parse_claim(self, response):
    """save available domain's details"""
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    # eliminate redundancy
    results = data['DataTables']['Results']['Data'][0]
    # snake case is more pythonic
    trust_flow = results['TrustFlow']
    citation_flow = results['CitationFlow']
    ref_domains = results['RefDomains']
    ext_back_links = results['ExtBackLinks']

    # don't need to wrap everything in ()
    if ref_domains > 20 and trust_flow > 4 and citation_flow > 4:
        insert_table(domain, trust_flow, citation_flow, ref_domains, ext_back_links)
```

This way your code is not being blocked and is fully asynchronious. Generally you don't want to use anything but scrapy requests when dealing with http in your scrapy spider.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and improve the code. I will try that !

Comment: I'm using a BloomFilter and I have lot of errors in the logs `raise IndexError("BloomFilter is at capacity")`. Do you know why ?

Comment: @Pixel sorry, I'm not really familiar with it. AFAIK according to `pybloom` wiki it should open up a new bigger instance. You can try specifying capacity when creating the filter. I don't think this is scrapy related and you'd probably want to open up a new question for it :)

Comment: @Pixel sorry I'm not on skype but if you have any questions you can find me on #python as `tinarg` on `irc.freenode.org`